# Will I draw more power/use more energy if I add an additional heater?

Tags: heating

I currently have one baseboard heater in my bedroom, I wanted to add another heater because it gets very cold and I have two exterior walls and only one heater. Will I be consuming more energy because I'm adding an additional heater?

Comment: What do you mean by "running more heat"?

Comment: Will more heat be used if I add an extra heater, or same amount of heat as having one heater in the room.

Comment: I'm still unclear what you're asking.  Heat is not used, it's produced.  If your heaters are electric, then you will use more electricity. If they are hot water or steam radiators, then you will use more energy producing that source.

Comment: Are you asking if you will use more energy because you furnace is heating an additional radiator?

Comment: The higher the indoor temperature, the more heat lost to the outside, so more energy is required to maintain that higher indoor temperature.

Comment: Yes, I am asking if I will use more energy because my furnace is heating an additional radiator? Thank you mikes

Comment: If your room is too cold now (presumably because of heat loss to the outside), and you add an additional heater that keeps your room warmer (because now the two heaters can produce more heat than you're losing to the outside), you'll use more energy. If you want to keep your room warmer without using more energy, you'll need to reduce the heat loss by sealing cracks that let cold air in, better windows (or plastic film over the windows, heavy insulating drapes can help too), and better insulation.

Comment: Why is this on hold?   It is not unclear what is being asked.   He says "it gets very cold" so this means he intends to heat the room to a higher temperature than it is now.   If the room is warmer, then more energy is lost to the outside because of more thermal difference.   So yes, it will use more energy.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't mention how your home is heated, but the general answer to this is **yes**.  A forced air furnace will use more gas. An electric baseboard heater will use more electricity. A hot water/steam system will use more electricity/gas depending on how it's powered.